# Why does all of X11 crash when issue is in one program

Tags: x11, windows

Coming from a Windows world, I often have to reorient myself when working in Linux. One of those times happened again today, when I started a GUI program and all of X11 went down - taking down my web browser, text editors, etc. In the (modern) Windows world, one program might hang or crash, but rarely does this cause all GUIs to go down.

What do most Linux users do with X11 to keep this from happening?

Comment: Usually, if one GUI program hangs or crashes, it doesn't take anything else down (though breaking grabs can be a pain). If the X11 server, or an X11 driver, has a bug, *then* everything goes down - but the last time that happened to me must be decades ago.

Comment: @dirkt adding on to this. This is still problematic because of the way GPU drivers are a part of X.

Comment: Is it one special application that causes the crash? Or do you use Adobe flash player, that is known to sometimes crash X at all? A look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` can help.

Answer (score 2):

That should not be how things should work. Usually the program will crash or something, but however, this may mean a more underlying problem with the drivers. If this happens again I recommend (if your on Ubuntu)
1. Hit `ctrl + alt + f2` (or something to that extent) to load the terminal
2. `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. Then `sudo service lightdm start`
or `sudo /etc/init.d/lxdm stop`. Then `sudo /etc/init.d/lxdm start`(I am not sure if this is platform specific).
By default Ubuntu will use lightdm, however, this may change if you are NOT using unity or gnome...
I recommend using proprietary drivers or very stable open source drivers (if you are that guy). Best of luck.